# Monotonic sequence with a bounded subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

What is the proof of the following theorem?

"If a sequence is monotonic and has a bounded subsequence, then it is also bounded."

Comment: What is a limited sequence?

Comment: Sorry, my native language is not English so I just translated the word we use. What I mean is that there is a number bigger than any number in the sequence and that there is another number smaller than any number in the sequence.

I think it's called bounded. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the sequence be $(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$.
Since it is monotonic
(assumed increasing here; decreasing works the same way),
$a_i \le a_{i+1}$ for all $i$.

By assumption,
it has a bounded subsequence
$(a_{i_j})_{j=1}^{\infty}$,
where $i_j < i_{j+1}$ for all $j$.

Since this is bounded (using bounded above here),
there is a $B$ such that $a_{i_j} \le B$
for all $j$.
Since this is a subsequence,
for any $k$ there is a $j$ such that
$k \le i_j$
(we can choose any $j \ge k$ by the
subsequence property).

Since $a_{i_j} \le B$ and
$k \le i_j$ and
$a$ is monotonic increasing,
$a_k \le B$.
Therefore the whole sequence is bounded (by $B$).

This is for monotonic increasing.
In this case, $a_i \ge a_1$ for all $i$,
so we get this trivial lower bound.

For monotonic decreasing,
reverse all the inequalities.

Comment: Nice answer mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP means "bounded."  A bounded monotone sequence can be shown to be Cauchy, and a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence must converge to that subsequential limit.

Comment: I agree that the OP means bounded, but the rest of your answer is not quite about what the OP asked.